# How to add continuous text to a shape that was created with shape builder tool in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, mask, text-wrap

I need a continuous text in a shape that has been built with a shape builder tool (Let's say doughnut shape). I need the text to continuously flow in the "doughnut", and leave the inside circle empty. Filling the ellipse with text and then cutting out the center text is not an option. As I said, the text has to be continuous.

As of right now, when I create a shape and click on the Area Type tool I get a message that says " you must click on a non-compound, non-masking path to create text inside a path".

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Update: 
Sample Picture added:[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the **outer path** with `Group selection tool`

   1. Copy it
   2. Deselect
   3. Paste in Front
2. `Object > Path > Offset path...`

   - Optional step that you will want to do if you don't want the text to be hugging the outside edge of the object.
3. Write text within the offset object
4. If you did step `2`, remove the original object that you offset the path from.
5. Select the **inner path** with `Group selection tool`

   1. Copy it
   2. Deselect
   3. Paste in Front
6. Set fill color to `none`
7. `Object > Text wrap > Make`
8. `Object > Text wrap > Text wrap options...`

   - ...if you want to adjust the inner offset.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to show me this! 

That's not exactly what I am looking for,though. I need the doughnut (Or any other complicated shape) to be shaped from a lot of text (horizontal text) lines. In other words, the inner circle should make the text jump over it and let the text continue on the other side of the inner circle...

Comment: I think you may need to add an example image. I'm not getting it.

Comment: Possibly also move over to inDesign @KristinaPetruitytė

Comment: Picture added to the original post! Thank you!

Comment: @KristinaPetruitytė Updated the answer.